Why result of Bayesian Sequential updates is not same as simultaneous updates?
Imagine such a problem, $y=ax+b+\epsilon$, and $a\sim U(lower_a, upper_a)$, and $b\sim U(lower_b, upper_b)$, and $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$. Then ,if i have $y_1$ and $y_2$ from $x_1$ and $x_2$, then if I sequentially update the distribution of a and b, I will always get uniform posteriors of them (because one observations could not determine two parameter, so they are uniform in the interval). But if I use two observations $y_1$ and $y_2$, I could determine the a and b now.
Why? What's wrong with the Bayesian sequential update?

If I understand your question correctly, it seems that in the Bayesian sequential update you start with a prior joint distribution for $(a,b)$ which is uniform on $(lower_a, upper_a) \times (lower_b, upper_b)$.  Being uniform, its density on its support is constant.
You first observe $(x_1,y_1)$ and update the initial prior joint distribution for $(a,b)$ with the likelihood for $\epsilon_1 = y_1-ax_1-b$ to a posterior joint distribution. This posterior joint distribution has a density on its support proportional to $\exp\big(-(y_1-ax_1-b)^2/2\big)$.
Using that posterior joint distribution as the new prior joint distribution, you next observe $(x_2,y_2)$ and update that joint distribution with the likelihood for $\epsilon_2 = y_2-ax_2-b$ to a second posterior joint distribution.  That posterior joint distribution has a density on its support proportional to $\exp\big(-(y_1-ax_1-b)^2/2\big)\exp\big(-(y_2-ax_2-b)^2/2\big)$ $=\exp\Big(-\big((y_1-ax_1-b)^2+(y_2-ax_2-b)^2\big)/2\Big)$.
The second posterior joint density is the same as you would have got if you had instead used the two observations $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ together instead of sequentially.  Neither would allow you to "determine the $a$ and $b$" but the final posterior joint distribution will be more concentrated than the initial uniform distribution.
